# Google Analytics opt out for mobile devices such as iPhone?

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to implement google analytics opt out extension on a mobile browser?  I am developing a site and it requires checking the site out on mobile. How do I stop the google analytics code that is in my site from picking up these views?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related

Comment: How is it not programming related if it deals with actual code?

Comment: if it deals with actual code please edit your question and add your code an example we can test and any issues you are having with your current solution

Answer (score 1):

The question is not fully clear - do you have problem with some part of code responsible for Google Analytics service? Or you just want to exclude your testing visits. In other words you don't want to clutter Google Analytics reports with your data (testing visits etc.).

If this second case is a sense of your question, then the easiest way is to create a filter (based on your network IP) in Google Analytics.

To create a filter, please:

1/ Login to Google Analytics
2/ Go to the ADMIN section
3/ In Account column, please enter "All Filters"
4/ Click red button Add filter
5/ Use predefined filter > exclude > traffic from IP adresses

[image: here you have to configure your filter]

If this is not the answer which you expect, please give more details :)

Comment: Ive tried this but this and alone it did not work for the browser on computers. So i added google analytics opt out and it worked for computers. However, on mobile, even though Ive got the IP address blocked, analytics still records the views. So, my question is, how do I disable for moblile

Answer (score 0):

In your backend, which generates your site (HTML), you should detect using User-Agent if the client is in fact a mobile device and do not add Google Analytics (or GTM) script to the page.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I only want it to opt out for my mobile device as well my colleagues. But I want the customers data to still be able to be logged in google analytics. Would I try to add in the ip address somehow?

Comment: So, you only want to block a few specific mobile devices (phones) but not all of them?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Just the office mobile phones.